# How does water get into the dishwasher door?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch dishwasher and got the E:15 (anti flood shutoff) alert.  I got into the pan underneath and the water there was very moldy.  I cleaned it out and while running a cycle, I don't see any obvious leaks.

To get access, I had to remove the door panel.  Toward the bottom, there's visible buildup, and it appears there is a drain from the door into the lower pan.  I suppose this could be (at least part) of the water source.

[image]

There's a drain here, so water intrusion must be assumed at times.  But where can it enter, or what can lead to intrusion here?  I can see that the door seal might not be perfect, but I wouldn't think leaks there would lead into the door, but onto the floor or into the pan directly.

I'll clean the door seals as well as I can, but anything else that can verify if this is the source of the water or prevent water into the door?

[image]

To answer a comment about the geometry of the door, the black material is a thin insulation on the "punch-out" molding portion of the door.  With the door open you can see the shape.

[image]

---

Just to add, it appears my original assumption (that the water in the pan is old) is incorrect.  After cleaning it up, I got some more water, even when the unit was not in use.  I added some food coloring into the sump and a few hours later the water in the pan turned green.  So rather than bother fully understanding why I have these deposits in the door, it looks like I need to replace the sump seal...

Comment: What's this bent bit & how does it marry to the structure when fully assembled? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPxhX.png It's really tough to see how parts fit together from one single 2D photo, compared to being able to see it in 3D, in situ.

Comment: The dishwasher is assembled (and running) in this photo.  The only thing removed is the outer panel from the door, some insulation, and the flood sensor was pulled out out the pan (but not unplugged).  The bend in the photo is one of 3 symmetric bends.  I suspect that it is crimped as part of the door assembly.  The photo was in tight to see the buildup.  I'll add one that is pulled back a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't water poured on an open door end at the same place? (ex: putting a glass still containing liquid or openning the door during/right after operation)

Comment: Water in the open door should (when the door is closed) run down into the wash basin.  And the lower door seal appears to me to be below where the buildup is happening.  So it's not simply water getting past that lower seal.  The side seals are higher than that, but I'm confused how water would then flow toward the front panel rather than straight down.

Comment: Bent bit could be if/when someone tried opening door when item on floor was in seam between door and washer, then opening with force? Kid's toy in just right spot, then open door

Comment: The bent bit is normally secured behind the door panel.  There's no access to it when buttoned up.  It looks to me like the bend is an intentional crimp as part of the assembly process.